# Do we need to write test class which refereed in another class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I referenced a class in another class called FCPAClass. The FCPAClass code coverage is 87% and the referenced class is showing 0 % coverage. So do I need to write a test class for that or is there no need? I tried but I couldn't. If I need to write one, can any one please suggest what should be covered in the test class?

[image]

```
public class FCPAanswersSendanEmailClass {
public static void sendEmailToAuthor(Map<id,List<Question_Answer__c>> sendingMap , Map<id,Question_Answer__c> oldValues){
    for(id aid : sendingMap.keySet()){
  // Step 1: Create a new Email
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

  string Subject =  '<br/>';
        string AccountName = '';
        system.debug('+++++++'+ sendingMap.keySet());
  for(Question_Answer__c bk : sendingMap.get(aid)){

     system.debug('====aid==='+ aid);
         AccountName = bk.Account__r.name;
          String Recordlink =  System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm().remove('devfull-commscope.') + '/'+bk.id;   

       //  String Recordlink = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm().remove('devfull-commscope.' ) + '/'+bk.id;               
         Subject = Subject +'<br/>'+  Recordlink;
         Subject = Subject +'<br/>'+'Question: <br/>'+ bk.Question__c;
         Subject = Subject +'<br/>'+'Previous Answer is : <br/>'+ oldValues.get(bk.id).Answer__c;
         Subject = Subject + '<br/>'+'Current Answer is : <br/>'+ bk.Answer__c + '<br/>'+'<br/>'; 

    }
   set<id> LegalTeamId = New set<id>();
  List<String> mailAddresses = new List<String>();
  set<id> grpUserIds = new set<id>();
  List<Legalemails__c> groupLst = Legalemails__c.getall().values();
  System.debug('Group List ++ '+groupLst.size());
  Map<string,string> groupMap = new Map<string,string>();
  for(Legalemails__c g : groupLst){
    groupMap.put(g.name ,g.groupId__c );
  }
  System.debug('Group List ++ '+groupMap);
        User Usr = new User();
        Usr = [SELECT AccountId, Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
        system.debug('=======currentuser'+ Usr);
 Accreditation__c Partnerregion = [SELECT Region__c,Territory_Name__c FROM Accreditation__c WHERE Account__c = :Usr.AccountId limit 1];
System.debug('Region +++ '+Partnerregion.Region__c);

 If(Partnerregion.Region__c == 'APAC' && Partnerregion.Territory_Name__c != 'china'){
    LegalTeamId.add(groupMap.get('Legal Approvers - APAC minus China'));
  } 
  else if(Partnerregion.Region__c == 'CALA'){
    LegalTeamId.add(groupMap.get('Legal Approvers - CALA'));
  }
  else if(Partnerregion.Region__c == 'CALA'){
    LegalTeamId.add(groupMap.get('Legal Approvers - APAC minus China'));
        }
  else if(Partnerregion.Region__c == 'APAC' &&  Partnerregion.Territory_Name__c == 'china'){        
      LegalTeamId.add(groupMap.get('Legal Approvers - China'));
  }
  else if(Partnerregion.Region__c == 'Europe' || Partnerregion.Region__c == 'MEA'){        
         LegalTeamId.add(groupMap.get('Legal Approvers - EMEA'));
  }
  else if(Partnerregion.Region__c == 'NAR'){        
     LegalTeamId.add(groupMap.get('Legal Approvers - NAR'));
        }
system.debug('+++ '+LegalTeamId);
list<GroupMember>  CALAreg  = [SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN:LegalTeamId];
for(GroupMember gid :CALAreg)
grpUserIds.add(gid.UserOrGroupId);
  List<user> Lteam = [Select email FROM user WHERE id IN : grpUserIds];
for(user Lt : Lteam){
 mailAddresses.add(Lt.email);               
 }
 system.debug('=======finalmail'+ mailAddresses);


  String body = 'Dear Legal <br/> Please review the FCPA changes for:   '+ AccountName + Subject ;
        mail.setSubject('FCPA Questions changed for '+ usr.Name +' during Annual Planning');
  mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        mail.setToAddresses(mailAddresses);           
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] {mail});
}  
}
}
```

Comment: In addition to crop's answer, the most likely reason that the referenced class has 0% coverage is the line that calls it is not covered in your main class. If you update the test to cover the scenario where updateAnswer_Account is NOT empty then you will have some coverage of the email class (not that coverage by itself matters) then you just need to figure how to verify things went as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Chris

Best practice is that all classes get both code coverage and System.assert coverage with the latter being more important (a side effect of assert coverage is you get code coverage if you design your tests well)

A common practice is to have one test class per underlying class being tested -- this can serve you well for unit tests.  You may also have additional test classes that do integration testing (or just more testmethods in one test class that verify the whole execution thread does what it is supposed to)

Your method `sendEmailToAuthor` is suitable for unit testing by passing in a variety of input arguments for each of the business use cases. You will need to mock some SObject data though -- `Accreditation__c` for example.

You won't really know if you are covering all of your classes until you run **all** tests and inspect code coverage results (you can use the Developer Console for this). But again, code coverage *per se* is not the goal, the goal is a suite of regression tests that proves the code does what it is supposed to do (and code coverages comes for "free" once you do that)